# Where is libclang.so?

Tags: vim, clang, libclang, clang-complete

I am using Linux Mint and I installed clang_complete using the makefile from [Clang Complete](https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete), but it does not work. When I open a cpp file, there is an error message:

```
Loading libclang failed, completion won't be available. Consider setting g:clang_library_path
```

I already did some research on this topic and tried to find the libclang.so file to put `g:clang_library_path= '...'` into my vimrc, but I cannot find the file so I cannot define the path in my vimrc.

`$ find / -name libclang  -type f 2> /dev/null` doesn't return anything.

How do I make clang_complete work?

Comment: Obviously you'll need to install clang (or libclang if it's available in a separate package) for that.

Comment: ok I've done "apt-get install clang". But code completion in vim is still not working...

Comment: Related, for future readers: https://github.com/Sarcasm/irony-mode/issues/140

Answer (score 23):

You probably have `libclang.so.1` in `/usr/lib/x86_64-unknown-linux` or somewhere similar. Make a symbolic link named as `libclang.so` in any of your library path would solve the problem (at least for me).

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-unknown-linux
ln -s libclang.so.1 libclang.so
```

Answer (score 12):

You need to install libclang. On my Ubuntu system it is in the "libclang1" package. Clang compiler and libclang are in different packages.

Comment: now there is a libclang.so.1 file in usr/lib/ . But defining usr/lib/ as clang_library_path does not change anything. still the same error.

Comment: ok :) usr/lib now contains libclang.so . But let clang_library_path= 'usr/lib' in my vimrc still doesn' t change anything...

Comment: you should use clang_library_path= '/usr/lib' not 'usr/lib'
if it does not work remove  clang_library_path variable. /usr/lib is default path. it should find library automatically there

Comment: mhh it's still "loading liblang failed". Maybe I should try to install clang_complete again: Do you think https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete works? I did "git clone https://github.com/Rip-Rip/clang_complete.git" in my .vim directory and then "make install"..

Comment: Try to clone git repository to some other directory, and then do make install...
I use clang_complete from git hub and it works fine.

Comment: ok I removed it and installed it this way. it' s still not working. I ve installed omnigppcomplete before but deleted the directories in .vim . Do you have another idee maybe?

Comment: how can I check this?

Comment: vim --version | grep python
you should see "+python" in the output. If there is "-python" then vim compiled without python support

Comment: there is +python but -python3

Comment: that's ok clang-complete does not need python3
I have no idea....
Does it still con't find library? Or something else?

Comment: it 's still loading libclang failed

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue with Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS:

```
Loading libclang failed, completion won't be available. Are you sure '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang-6.0.so.1' contains libclang?
```

I fixed it using:

1. Install libclang

   ```
   sudo apt install clang
   ```
2. Add following in .vimrc to use latest installed libclang

   ```
   let g:clang_library_path = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libclang-10.so.1'
   ```

If needed, adjust "libclang-10.so.1" to use the clang version that was installed.

You should be good with Vim at this point.

Comment: In a mix of helpful answers, this one was the solver for me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In $clang_complete/plugin/libclang.py, there is a code like this:

```
debug = int(vim.eval("g:clang_debug")) == 1
```

So use `let g:clang_debug=1` to enable clang debug.

For me, the error is:

```
/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCCC_3.x.xx' not found
```

Set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to a third libstdc++ will solve this.